# NodeJS async/await: Why is my Array becoming 1 in the async/await call back?

Tags: arrays, node.js, callback, async-await

The question in title is pretty straightforward... I have no idea what's happening.
I have a promise, then an async/await function to callback the value from the promise but instead of getting the correct values, the Array generated in the promise becomes a plain '1'.

Here's my code:

```
    var async = require('async');
    var request = require('request');
    var _ = require('underscore');

    var getTickerList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var tickerArr = [];
      request({
        url: 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs',
        json: true
      }, (error, response, body) => {

        var jsonObject = body;
        _.map(jsonObject, function(content) {
          _.map(content, function(data) {
            if (data.altname.indexOf('EUR') !== -1 || data.altname.indexOf('USD') !== -1)
              resolve(tickerArr.push(data.altname));
              // resolve(tickerArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
          });
        });
        console.log(tickerArr);
      })
    });


    async function exec() {
      var tickerList = await getTickerList;
      debugger;
      console.log(tickerList);
    }

exec()
```

I've tried to avoid all of the function that operates on the request and simply put a resolve(tickerArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and it shows up correctly so I guess that it is some part of the _.map operation that is messing with the process, but how? And where?

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('underscore');

var getTickerList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var tickerArr = [];
  request({
    url: 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs',
    json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {

    // var jsonObject = body;
    // _.map(jsonObject, function(content) {
    //   _.map(content, function(data) {
    //     if (data.altname.indexOf('EUR') !== -1 || data.altname.indexOf('USD') !== -1)
    //       resolve(tickerArr.push(data.altname));
          resolve(tickerArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
    //   });
    // });
    console.log(tickerArr);
  })
});


async function exec() {
  var tickerList = await getTickerList;
  debugger;
  console.log(tickerList);
}
```

Any idea what's happening here? In the end, I'll be exporting the promise to a main and it'll remain as a module...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your version of node supports `async`, you don't need to import anything, `async` is a reserved word that is part of the language, like `if` or `var`

Comment: You don't delete the `async` part in your functions, you delete the `var async = require('async');` part.

Comment: Done! Thanks again, it indeed looks better. The problem is still there though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#push()` returns the `length` of the array after appending the values supplied in the parameters of the function call, it does *not* return the modified array. Your first `resolve()` is the only one that gets `await`'ed, and since the `length` would be `1` after pushing the first element, that's the value that gets resolved.

Comment: Ok so basically I would need to call the resolve once the array has been fully built: instead of the console log I have for control

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick! It worked perfectly: `resolve(tickerArr);` right instead of my console log!